# Bind NetworkManager managed dnsmasq to device when it appears

Tags: virtualbox, dnsmasq, networkmanager

I have couple of servers running in VirtualBox interconnected by hosted-only network. The parent system is Ubuntu running NetworkManager which manages the DNS according to the connected network so my `resolv.conf` contains

```
nameserver 127.0.1.1
```

The VirtualBox is configured that the parent system has address `10.1.0.1` and the virtual servers are statically configured to `10.1.0.2`, `10.1.0.3`....

When I change network I always find (via `nmcli`) my actual nameserver and fill the value to each of the virtual servers. This is annoying as I frequently change the network and connect via different interfaces (`wlan0`, `eth0`).

My idea is to use the NetworkManager managed DNS server as server for the virtuals. But when I put nameserver `10.1.0.1` in resolv.conf of the virtual servers the DNS is not resolved.

Clearly the DNS server managed by the NetworkManager is bound only to `127.0.1.1`.

I tried to add `listen-interface=10.1.0.1` to `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d/<my-file>` it works after NetworkManager restart but only when the Virtual Box is running and the `vboxnet0` interface exists. When the Virtual Box is down the `dnsmasq` fails to start.

I also tried use `bind-dynamic` option to dnsmasq but it is incompatible with `bind-interface` added to `dnsmasq` command by NetworkManager.

**Question:** How can I make the NetworkManager to bind dnsmasq to `10.1.0.1` after `vboxnet0` interface appears? Or how to make it to start another instance of `dnsmasq` forwarding `10.1.0.1` request to `127.0.1.1`?

### Additional info:

```
# ifconfig
...
vboxnet0  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0a:00:27:00:00:00  
inet addr:10.1.0.1  Bcast:10.1.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
...
```

-

```
# ps aux|grep dnsmasq
nobody    1252  0.0  0.0  52976  4108 ?        S    dub10   0:00 
/usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts
--bind-interfaces --pid-file=/var/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.pid 
--listen-address=127.0.1.1 --cache-size=0 --conf-file=/dev/null 
--proxy-dnssec --enable-dbus=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq 
--conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d
```

-

```
#netstat -antp|grep ':53'
tcp 0 0 127.0.1.1:53   0.0.0.0:* LISTEN 1252/dnsmasq
```

-

```
# nslookup google.com 127.0.1.1
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 64.233.164
```

-

```
# nslookup google.com 10.1.0.1
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be resolved (heh) with a wrapper script for `dnsmasq` to replace `--bind-interfaces` with `--bind-dynamic`, but for some reason `NetworkManager` hardcodes its search path, so first the original binary has to be moved out of the way (on `dpkg`-based systems, use a command like `dpkg-divert --local --rename --divert /usr/local/sbin/dnsmasq --add /usr/sbin/dnsmasq`).

Then create a new `/usr/sbin/dnsmasq`:

```
#!/bin/bash

args=("$@")
for (( i=0; i<${#args}; ++i )); do
    case "${args[i]}" in
    -z|--bind-interfaces)
        args[i]=--bind-dynamic
        ;;
    --)
        break
        ;;
    esac
done

exec /usr/local/sbin/dnsmasq "${args[@]}"
```

Change `/usr/local/sbin/dnsmasq` as needed to point to the original binary, mark the script as executable (`chmod +x /usr/sbin/dnsmasq`), and add whatever `interface=` lines to a file in `/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d`.

### Caveats:

1. Use of `/usr/local/sbin` might break if `NetworkManager` is updated to honor the `PATH` environment variable. If this is a concern, move the real executable to a non-`PATH` location such as `/usr/lib` (but see #2 below).
2. Use of a location that isn't before `/usr/sbin` in `$PATH` will cause `--bind-interfaces` (`-z`) to be replaced when manually invoking `dnsmasq` on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Extending @lumato-reinstate-monica's answer above, as I can't put additional code blocks in a comment.

I also found it useful to unset the localhost `listen-address` option as `bind-dynamic` has that covered.

```
--listen-address=*)
        unset args[i]
        args=(${args[@]})
        ;;
```

Setting `bind-dynamic` alongside network-manager's setting of `listen-address=127.0.1.1` was generating error messages to the effect that dnsmasq couldn't bind twice to the same address:port, which this configuration is asking for. Perhaps dnsmasq ought to detect that scenario, but it doesn't.